# Javascript: Manipulate array to return shortest node

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array as below

```js
var a = [ [ 5, 5, 1, -4 ], [ 3, 7, 3, -1 ], [ 7, 3, 4, 1 ], [ 5, 5, 5, 0 ] ]
```

Every nested array index:2 element indicates its distance from 0(Zero) and every index:3 element indicate how near it is to its next poll point.

I am trying to sort this array so I can get nested array which is near to index:0 with reference to index:2 element and its next poll point is very near.

For example, my answer here is `[ 3, 7, 3, -1 ]` because

- though `[ 5, 5, 1, -4 ]` , index:2 is very near to 0 its next point is located at after/before 4 positions. But for `[ 3, 7, 3, -1 ]` next poll point is at one position.

I tried with sorting like below

js

```
inDiff = inDiff.sort( function(a,b ){      
      if ( a[2] < b[2]) {
        if ( Math.abs(a[3]) < Math.abs(b(3)) ){
          return Math.abs(b[3]) - Math.abs(a[3]);
        }
      }
    });
```

#### Update 1

As asked in the comment I am adding explanation to each element of the nested array. For example in nested array [ 5, 5, 1, -4 ]

Index:0: Value 5 Represents 1st Number that I am looking for

Index:1 Value 5 Represents 2nd Number ( next poll point number)

By Adding these two numbers I will achieve my requirement of finding two numbers which can sum up for 10.

Index 2 : Value 1 : Indicates index of 1st number nothing but 5 in the source array

Index 3 : Value -4 : Indicates difference between indexes of Index:0 and Index:1 number of nested array from source array.

But nothing happens with my array.
Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: Can you more clearly layout what each index in the sub array represents?

Comment: @Kwright02 Updated my question, could you please review now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the input always follows requirements this demo uses `.reduce()`

```js
const AA = [
  [5, 5, 1, -4],
  [3, 7, 3, -1],
  [7, 3, 4, 1],
  [5, 5, 5, 0]
];

let result = AA.reduce((min, now, idx, AoA) => {
  let distTo0 = array => Math.abs(Math.floor(array[2]) + Math.floor(array[3]));
  min = distTo0(now) < distTo0(min) ? now : min;
  return min;
});

console.log(result);
```

The following demo includes all of the rules as I understood them:

```js
const crazyLogic = arrayOfArrays => {
  let AAClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arrayOfArrays));
  const shared = AAClone[0][0] + AAClone[0][1];
  const rules = [`Must be an array of number arrays`, `The sum of index 0 and 1 of each sub-array must be identical`, `Mismatched sub-array lengths`];
  let message = !AAClone.every(sub => Array.isArray(sub)) ? rules[0] : !AAClone.every(sub => sub.every(num => num + 0 === num)) ? rules[0] : !AAClone.every(sub => sub[0] + sub[1] === shared) ? rules[1] : !AAClone.every(sub => sub.length === 4) ? rules[2] : null;
  if (message !== null) {
    return message;
  }
  return AAClone.reduce((min, now, idx, AoA) => {
    let distTo0 = array => Math.abs(Math.floor(array[2]) + Math.floor(array[3]));
    min = distTo0(now) < distTo0(min) ? now : min;
    return min;
  });
};

/* Input rules:
1. Must be an array of arrays (only numbers)
2. Each sum of subArray[0] + subArray[1] must be identical
3. Each subArray.length = 4
*/
// AAa returns [ 3, 7, 3, -1 ] 
const AAa = [
  [5, 5, 1, -4],
  [3, 7, 3, -1],
  [7, 3, 4, 1],
  [5, 5, 5, 0]
];

// AA1 breaks rule 1
const AA1 = [
  [5, 5, 1, -4],
  [3, 7, 3, -1],
  [7, 3, ' X', 1],
  [5, 5, 5, 0]
];

// AAO breaks rule 1
const AAO = [
  [5, 5, 1, -4],
  [3, 7, 3, -1],
  [7, 3, 4, 1],
  [5, 5, 5, 0], {}
];

// AA2 breaks rule 2
const AA2 = [
  [5, 5, 1, -4],
  [3, 17, 3, -1],
  [7, 3, 4, 1],
  [5, 5, 5, 0]
];

// AA3 breaks rule 3
const AA3 = [
  [5, 5, 1, -4],
  [3, 7, 3, -1],
  [7, 3, 4, 1],
  [5, 5, 5]
];

console.log(crazyLogic(AAa));

console.log(crazyLogic(AA1));
console.log(crazyLogic(AAO));
console.log(crazyLogic(AA2));
console.log(crazyLogic(AA3));
```